# Angular: ng-show stale state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I'm using `ng-show` to show a div upon clicking a button.

The div I'm `ng-show`-ing contains a course schedule with dynamically updated courses as the user clicks around and adds courses.

But when this course schedule gets triggered to show, it is in a stale state.  There are no courses appearing.

Any insight onto why all the added courses data is not actually showing?  Is there something special that has to be done after `ng-show` to refresh the state of the data?

HTML:

```
    <div id="schedule-div" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" ng-show="scheduleMode" calendar="weekView"></div>
```

JS:

```
// Event handle for "Generate Schedule" button
$scope.getSchedules = function () {
    scheduleFactory.getSchedules($rootScope.addedCourses).
        success(function (data) {
            var scheduleListing = angular.fromJson(data);

            // Create closure with current scheduleListing
            scheduleInstance = renderSchedule(scheduleListing);
            scheduleInstance(0);

            // $scope.events is the data used
            // This log correctly, logs data
            console.log($scope.events);

            // Toggle the ng-show
            $scope.scheduleMode = true;

        }).
        error(function() {
            $window.alert("Schedules not found.");
        });
};
```

As you can see this is all happening in a callback from the server (I don't think this should matter though).  The `console.log()` shows the data correctly so the data **does exist** by the time the `ng-show` is toggled.

When the `ng-show` logic is **completely removed the data is correctly updated** in the schedule view. So the problem must lie somewhere in `ng-show` displaying a stale state.

Comment: As @Manish Said, post a plunker or code atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data source. ng-show doesn't care about the content. It just make the container display:none or display:block based on the condition.

Your datasource is not getting updated.

If you have any example than post.

Answer (score 0):

after code

```
// Toggle the ng-show
$scope.scheduleMode = true;
```

add

```
$scope.apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `ng-model=eventSources` to set your data in the schedule listing. It doesn't appear to be updated, as the variable `eventSources` isn't being used in your `getSchedules()` code. That controls what get's updated inside the `div`.

`ng-show` only shows or hides the div, doesn't control anything else inside of it.